# Where is a VB.NET Static variable stored?

Tags: vb.net, memory-management, virtual, shared

I want to know where a VB.NET local static variable is stored in the program's virtual address space, and how does a sub-routine/method retain its value between calls?

I have searched extensively online in order to understand the VB.NET virtual address space for a process.  There are plenty of diagrams and explanations for Java and C running on Linux, which include an area in virtual memory known 'shared' or 'data', but it is harder to find something specifically about VB.NET. As far as I can see, .NET does not utilise an area in the virtual address space of a process called 'shared'.  My question is, where is the data for a local static variable stored, and how does a sub-routine/method regain access to it between each time it is called?  Intuitively, I presume the shared variable's data is stored on one of the heaps (LOH or SOH) depending on size, and the sub-routine/method has a reference to this on it's stack.  But if the sub-routine ends, the stack frame is removed and the reference is lost.  How does it regain this reference?

Comment: Through some creative googling I found an old msdn magazine article, mirrored [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140724084944/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx), the original is apparently only available as a [.CHM file](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineMay2005en-us.chm). The details are a bit beyond me but does this answer the question?

Answer (score -1):

C++ and C# static variables are a bit different, for instance in C# programming language, you can use only class member static variables (C++ allows global static variables, as well static variables local to a function).
For some details on memory allocation you may look, for instance: "Static Keyword Demystified"[^] (C#), Where are static variables stored (in C/C++)?[^] (C++).

Comment: This question is asking about VB.NET, not C++ or C# (I believe you've interpreted this question as "Where are static variables stored?" rather than "Where are static variables stored in VB.NET?".